# Search and replace characters in the SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a long SQL query and have to modify the query by doing a search and replace for the below strings found. Can you please let me know the easiest way to achieve it.

1) Search and replace the

```
input string -  "ch.[No_] AS [Contract No.]"
```

as

```
output string - "ch.[No] AS [ContractNo.]"
```

2)

```
input string -  [Status Reason Code Description]
output string - [StatusReasonCodeDescription]
```

This search and replace has to scan the whole query and replace only if the above string is found, so that this modified query could be run in another DB

Comment: Do it in the text editor?

Comment: It can be any text with the above pattern, so the replace should be able to handle

Comment: What's wrong with `Ctrl` + `H` of the SQL Server editor?

Comment: Describe "the above pattern". Remove all underscores, or only those after a lowercase letter and followed by a right-square-bracket? Remove all whitespace within square brackets?

Comment: This question is missing crucial details. If it's just a find and replace what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I got you on this bro

1. Download Notepad++ https://notepad-plus-plus.org/
2. Ctrl+H to go to Replace Menu
3. Click "Replace" tab
4. Change "Search Mode" to "Regular expression"
5. Find what: `(\[.*?)\s(.*?\])`
6. Replace with: `\1\2`
7. Hit "Replace All" a bunch of times to get all the white spaces out.
8. Change Find what: `(\[.*?)-(.*?\])`
9. Hit "Replace All" a bunch of times to get all the dashes out.
10. Save it!

Screenshot for reference: 
[image]

Comment: Hell, SSMS can do this.

Comment: Haha, yeah true just use the SSMS text editor.. Maybe there's more to the question who knows...

Comment: I am actually looking for a specific search pattern in the whole query.

Comment: If a space is found between "[....]" it should be replaced . For e.g: if the string found is [Contract No.] it should be replaced with [ContractNo.].

Comment: Similaly if a "-" charecter is found between [..] replace with "" , e.g: [Contract-No] with [ContractNo]. It is not specific to any specific word wherever the pattern is found it should replace

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to replacing what by what!
But if the texts are static you can do following steps in the SQL Server editor:

1. Open the query in edit mode
2. Press `Ctrl` + `H`
3. In `Find what` box, type `input string -  "ch.[No_] AS [Contract No.]"`
4. In `Replace with` box, type `output string - "ch.[No] AS [ContractNo.]"`
5. Press `Replace all` button

For the next replacement do the same as above too.

...

3. In `Find what` box, type `input string -  "input string -  [Status Reason Code Description]`
4. In `Replace with` box, type `output string - "output string - [StatusReasonCodeDescription]`

...